# Regex remove part of a file name

Tags: regex

OS: Windows 10
Tool: PowerRename

I need to remove the # symbol and the number in a file name IE:

```
ABC 2020 Sec. Fund - 2021 - # 1 Doe, John.pdf
```

to

```
Doe, John - ABC 2020 Sec. Fund - 2021.pdf
```

Using this expression:|

```
/(^[^#]*)-(.*$)
```

And this substitution:

```
$2 $1
```

I get the following:

```
ABC 2020 Sec. Fund - 2021 - # 1 Doe, John.pdf
```

Becomes

```
# 1 Doe, John ABC 2020 Sec. Fund - 2021.pdf
```

There are multiple of these files that have to be renamed.

I need to make sure everything before the last name is removed. Everytime I add to this expression it breaks. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Is this part of a Bash script? We need more details to assist.

Comment: I apologize first time doing anything like this. I am using powerrenamer from PowerToys. Microsoft says it uses regex so I read what I thought I needed and was able to get this far. I added OS and program name to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose the following Regex :

```
(.*) - ([0-9]+) - # [0-9]+ (.*).pdf
```

With the following substitution pattern :

```
$3 - $1 - $2 .pdf
```

**Explanation:**

`(.*) -` match all char until the first `-`. The char before `-` are caught in first group

`([0-9]+)` Get all number between the first and the second `-` and catch it in the second group

`# [0-9]+ (.*).pdf` Get all char between the symbol `#` followed by one or several number, and `.pdf`, and catch it in the third group

**Check here :**

https://regex101.com/r/Fx5R6L/1

Comment: This looks like it works. I messed up and Missed something in the line though:

ABC 2020 Sec. Fund - 2021 M1 - # 1 Doe, John.pdf

Forgot the Schedule form name

I am reading the explanation. Is there an entry that allows to do number and character like 0-9,a-z

Comment: I am also confused as to why the first ([0-9]+) has the (+) but the 2ns does not

Comment: [0-9a-zA-Z] match number and character.

Comment: Answer edited to add more explanation

Answer (score 1):

So I need to add a "4th" set for the addition of the form type:

K1, M1, F3, ECT

ABC 2020 Sec. Fund - 2021 K1 - # 1 Doe, John.pdf

IE:
(.*?) - ([0-9]+) ([0-9a-zA-Z]+) - # [0-9]+ (.*?).pdf

Sub:
$4 $2 $3 - $1

Which would change:
ABC 2020 Targeted Sec. Fund - 2021 K1 - # 1 Doe, John.pdf
Into
Werner, Joseph K1 - 2021 ABC 2020 Targeted Sec. Fund

I think I get the feel for it you can separate each into its own group and excluding character by leaving them outside the any brackets.

@S. Brottes - epic explanation thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).